PM2 is repeatedly showing Module Not Found, Required Stack
I am deploying a node app on vps server on godaddy and getting this issue when i run pm2, When i start the pm2 it shows me status online, within secs when i check the status again it shows me errored, and when i check the logs, it shows module not found required stack,
i have tried:
to keep node version same
Update/upgrade Server
install and update Node modules
Update pm2
[root@42 Backend]# pm2 start server.js
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [server](ids: [ 0 ])
[PM2] [server](0) ✓
[PM2] Process successfully started
┌────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0  │ server    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 235064   │ 0s     │ 30   │ online    │ 0%       │ 11.0mb   │ root     │ disabled │
└────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
[root@42 Backend]# pm2 status
┌────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0  │ server    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 45   │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ root     │ disabled │
└────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

[root@42 Backend]# pm2 logs
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
/root/.pm2/pm2.log last 15 lines:
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:34: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:34: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:34: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:34: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:34: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:34: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:34: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2024-06-28T09:25:34: PM2 log: Script /root/ProamWeb/Backend/server.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"

/root/.pm2/logs/server-out.log last 15 lines:
/root/.pm2/logs/server-error.log last 15 lines:
0|server   |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
0|server   |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
0|server   |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
0|server   |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
0|server   |     at Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:101:39) {
0|server   |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
0|server   |   requireStack: [
0|server   |     '/root/ProamWeb/Backend/Controllers/Auth.controller.js',
0|server   |     '/root/ProamWeb/Backend/Controllers/index.js',
0|server   |     '/root/ProamWeb/Backend/Routes/Auth.route.js',
0|server   |     '/root/ProamWeb/Backend/Routes/index.js',
0|server   |     '/root/ProamWeb/Backend/app.js',
0|server   |     '/root/ProamWeb/Backend/server.js'
0|server   |   ]
0|server   | }


You should use install dependencies with npm or yarn!
in application directory:
npm install
pm2 restart <ID of your node process>

